# Solr: how to highlight the whole search phrase only?

Tags: solr

**A**  I  need to perform a phrase search. On the search results Im getting the exact phrase matches but looking at the highlighted parts  I see that the phrase are tokenized  i.e This is what I get when I search for the prase "Day 1" :

```
<arr name="post">
  <str><em>Day</em> <em>1</em>   We have begun a new adventure! An early morning (4:30 a.m.) has found me meeting with</str>
</arr>
```

This is what I want to receive as a result:

```
    <arr name="post">
  <str><em>Day 1</em>   We have begun a new adventure! An early morning (4:30 a.m.) has found me meeting with</str>
</arr>
```

**The query I m doing is this:**
Admin console:

```
q = day 1 
fq = post:"day 1" OR title:"day 1"
hl = true
hl.fl =title,post
```

select?q=day+1&fq=post%3A%22day+1%22+OR+title%3A%22day+1%22&wt=xml&indent=true&hl=true&hl.fl=title%2Cpost&hl.simple.pre=%3Cem%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fem%3E

Theese are my fields:

```
     <field name="post" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
      <field name="post" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

This is the solr schema section for my fied type text_general:

```
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />

    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**B)** I can see in the highlight section more disturbing results i.e highlighting not the whole word as expected but single fragments: `.where you get to see all of Athens ...  <em>Day</em> 2 -  Carmens`
I dont want to see this result  in the highlighted section (Only need to see both words "Day 1"). Any ideas ?

I m reading the Solr highlight section but .. really... there is not even 1 example!!!

Comment: I am a bit confused by the last section of your post. At the beginning you wrote that you received only Day 1 as the reply, while at the end you wrote you received another response. Which one is it?

Comment: All the docs contain "Day 1" but in some cases the field post can be = " Day 1 i did this and that ... where day 2 i did those other things ..." .  Im sure that in the docs section the result have minimum the phrase "Day 1" .  'The reply' comes in 2 flavors : the document and the highlight versions of those documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter that needed to be inserted was `hl.q` which basically means "I want this phrase to be highlighted" and hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true  and hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=true

So by adding to my original query : `&hl.q="Day+1"&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=true` worked.

for B) I changed `fq = post:"day 1" OR title:"day 1"` to `fq = post:"day 1"`. I know that the latter is less from what I need be neverthless is works.

fastVectorHighliter configuration that was used:

```
   <field name="post" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"  termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) I have found an option to join a highlight for elements that are next to each other.

The option is `hl.mergeContiguous`

Comment: There are numerous posts about the same question where this param didnt work and needles to say that was alredy tried and didnt work as well. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700916/solr-highlighting-every-word-individually-for-a-phrase-query

Comment: This refers to the fragments (aka snippets) not the highlights themselves