# Highlighting match phrase instead word phrase in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

We are working with percolators in ElasticSearch, and we need get a complete highlighting by phrase instead word by word:

As example, we have the next search:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my-index/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field": "query",
            "document" : {
                "title" : "A new bonsai tree in the office and jungle. The enojen tree in a kerojen."
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
      "fields": {
        "title": {}
      }
    }
}
'
```

And we get the next output:

```
{  
   "took":12,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{  
      "total":45,
      "max_score":2.1576157,
      "hits":[  
         {  
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_type":"_doc",
            "_id":"2",
            "_score":2.1576157,
            "_source":{  
               "query":{  
                  "match":{  
                     "title":"the enojen tree in a kerojen"
                  }
               }
            },
            "fields":{  
               "_percolator_document_slot":[  
                  0
               ]
            },
            "highlight":{  
               "title":[  
                  "<em>A</em> new bonsai <em>tree</em> <em>in</em> <em>the</em> office and jungle. <em>The</em> <em>enojen</em> <em>tree</em> <em>in</em> <em>a</em> <em>kerojen</em>."
               ]
            }
         },
         {  
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_type":"_doc",
            "_id":"1",
            "_score":2.1576157,
            "_source":{  
               "query":{  
                  "match":{  
                     "title":"the bonsai tree in a jungle"
                  }
               }
            },
            "fields":{  
               "_percolator_document_slot":[  
                  0
               ]
            },
            "highlight":{  
               "title":[  
                  "<em>A</em> new <em>bonsai</em> <em>tree</em> <em>in</em> <em>the</em> office and <em>jungle</em>. <em>The</em> enojen <em>tree</em> <em>in</em> <em>a</em> kerojen."
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, we are getting all highlighted matches splitted word by word, but we want get something like this: `<em>The enojen tree in a kerojen</em>`; there is a related [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29561) for it.

We were searching about it and we found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930180/solr-how-to-highlight-the-whole-search-phrase-only/25970452#25970452), but it is related with `Sorl`.

It says there are two possible parameters (from Lucene) for this purpose: `usePhraseHighlighter` and `mergeContiguous`.

So, how can we get a full phrase highlighting result instead highlighting every word individually for a phrase query?

Thank you.

Comment: issue connected to it: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, this should now be fixed as of [Elsticsearch 8.10](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/release-notes-8.10.0.html), as per https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/96068.